# How do I prevent the application layout from rendering twice when doing an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jqxhr

I want to populate the landing page of my app with index pages of other controllers using xhr calls whenever someone loads the homepage. However, whenever I try doing this, the layout gets rendered twice [image: multiple times.] I have tried a couple of things mentioned in other answers like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout proc { false if request.xhr? }
```

but my page is still loading the layout multiple times. What can I do to get around this?

Comment: how are you handling the xhr exactly? and can you show the basic structure of your application layout?

Comment: Can you show the action's code + template? Is the nav bar/CryptoPiazza part of the layout?

Comment: @Joel_Blum the XHR is like this 

`function populateExchangeTable(exchangeTable){
    fetch('/exchange').then((response)=> {
        response.text().then((text)=> {
            exchangeTable.innerHTML = text
            
        });
    });
}


function pageLoaded(){
    let exchangeTable = document.querySelector('.exchange-table');
    populateExchangeTable(exchangeTable)
    console.log('hello',exchangeTable);
}
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', pageLoaded);`

Comment: @stwienert this is the application.html.erb
 `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  
  <div class = "header">
    <h1> Crypto<strong>Piazza</strong></h1>
  </div>
  <% if logged_in?%>
    <div class = "headerlinks">
    Welcome  <%= current_user.username %> 
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
    </div>
  <% else%>
    <div class = "headerlinks">
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_path %>
    <%= link_to "Login", new_session_path %>`
  And yes, the navbar is part of the layout as well.